# Replace a substring from a string in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, replace, functional-programming

I have the following string `"not really//"` and I want to write a function that replaces every two slashes `"//"` with two dots `".."`

I thought about using map, but then I would iterate through characters and can't know if a slash is going to be followed by another or not. Any clue how this can be done? (without regex)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Explicit recursion looks fine here:

```
replace :: String -> String
replace ('/':'/':xs) = '.' : '.' : replace xs
replace (x:xs)       = x : replace xs
replace ""           = ""
```

This does not scale to long patterns, but for replacing "//" it should work fine.

Answer (score 15):

We can use the [**`replace :: Text -> Text -> Text -> Text`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:replace) function of the `Data.Text` function. For example:

```
Prelude Data.Text> replace "//" ".." "not really//"
"not really.."
```

Here we work however on `Text`s. If that is a problem, we can also use [**`pack :: String -> Text`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:pack) and [**`unpack :: Text -> String`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:unpack) to convert between `String` and `Text`. So we can define a function with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text(pack, unpack, replace)

replacedoubleslash :: String -> String
replacedoubleslash = unpack . replace "//" ".." . pack
```

But usually for efficient string processing - both in terms of speed and memory - using `Text` is better than working with `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any package, this is what I've come with:

```hs
isHead':: String -> String -> String -> Bool
isHead' str [] ret = True
isHead' [] key  ret = False
isHead' (x:xs) (x':xs') ret = (x == x') && isHead' xs xs' ret

isHead:: String -> String ->  Bool
isHead  key str= isHead' str key key

remouveXelem:: Int ->[a] -> [a]
remouveXelem i a | i <= 0 = a
remouveXelem _ [] = [] 
remouveXelem i (x:xs) = remouveXelem (i - 1) xs  

replace :: String -> String -> String -> String
replace ori new [] = []
replace ori new s = if isHead ori s then
    new ++ replace ori new (remouveXelem (length ori) s)
    else head s : replace ori new (tail s)
```

replace "i" "a" "il etait une fois" =>
"al etaat une foas"